# Why does interceptor not return data to subscriber?

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, angular7

I use interceptor in last Angular:

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
      map((event: any) => {
        if (request.method == "GET") {
          return event;
        }

        if (request.method == "POST") {
          if (event.body) {
            return event.body["result"];
          }
        }

        return event;
      }));
```

So, I check if it is `POST` request, I expect to get data from JSON with key `result`.

Also I tried to return data in Observer:

```
if (event.body) {
   return Observable.of(event.body["result"]);
}
```

And subscription is:

```
this.method.subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Look at this pic:

```
console.log(event); // This is default event - first selected area 
console.log(eventToSend); /./ This is modified   - second  selected area
```

[image]

Difference is type HttpResponse, it lacks in second modified object eventToSend

Comment: Can you replicate this on StackBlitz? Also try logging in case of error and completion.

Comment: It is whole code, that I have, I dont know is it correct using or not, should I return Observer back with data parsed from map?

Comment: An http interceptor is supposed to return an Observable<HttpEvent<any>>. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor. This code doesn't make much sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't think so. If you do that, then you'll have to use `switchMap` instead of `map` in there.

Comment: Therefore each response has structure `{"result": {}}` that I need to parse this and return  data without `result key`, Thats is main purpose.

Comment: Maybe add ` return eventToSend as HttpResponse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue using this approach:

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
      map((event: any) => {
        if (request.method == "POST") {
          if (request.body["$type"] == "LoginRequest") {
            return event;
          }

          if (event.body) {
            event.body = event.body["result"];
          }
        }

        return event;
      }),

      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error.status === 401) {
          this.route.navigate(["/login"]);
        }
        return throwError(
          "Ошибка сервера RequestInterception: " + error.message || error
        );
      })
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your interceptor needs to return the complete `event`(of type `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>`) instead of just the response `body`, but you still want to get just `result` in the response `body`, try this:

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
  map((event: any) => {
    // Removing this as it is redundant
    /*if (request.method == "GET") {
      return event;
    }*/

    if (request.method == "POST") {
      if (event.body) {
        const eventToSend = { ...event };
        eventToSend.body = event.body["result"];
        return eventToSend;
      }
    }
    return event;
  }));
```

Here, we're spreading the whole `event` object, and then reassigning the `body` property on it with `body['result']`

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-interceptor-eg?file=src%2Fapp%2Finterceptor.service.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Sure, it looks truthy Sure, it looks truthy, I need just retrieve from each result data by key ""result

Comment: It does not work still, subscriber does not see response

Comment: @OPV, I've updated my answer. I've also added a Sample StackBlitz for your ref. Can you please check if the updated answer is working for you?

Comment: HttpEvents are not POJOs. They're instances of specific classes, that are immutable, but have a clone() method allowing to create a copy with a different body. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpEvent, https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse. An interceptor should return an actual HttpEvent, not a POJO.

Comment: Problem is that it expects HttpResponse but I try return just data

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks a lot for sharing this. The Event did get change though. But now that I've read your comment, it looks like what I'm doing is an anti-pattern. How do you suggest I do it? I did try to clone the event Object and pass in my updated body. But I get a `backend comm error` when I do it.

Comment: @OPV, yeah that's what I've mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Anyway now it returns simple object not type `HttpResponse`. If follow you last answwer

Comment: @SiddAjmera https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whpvtj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: I have added pic to question, first it is default event, second is modified

Comment: Maybe add ` return eventToSend as HttpResponse`?